# Como passar variável para AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho uma tela onde listo várias músicas e ao lado tenho uma imagem que chama o AJAX para adicionar essa música numa *playlist*. Minha dúvida é como passar o ID dessa música para o AJAX, uma vez que não posso usar a URL, pois essa tem que estar com `#`.

```
    while($consulta2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {; 
      echo"<div class='album-musicas'><a href='musica.php?musica=$consulta2[id_musica]&artista=$consulta2[id_cantor_fk]&album=$consulta2[id_album_fk]' class='album-musicas-texto'>$consulta2[nr_faixa].  $consulta2[nm_musica]</a>";
      if ($consulta2["nm_som"] != '') { 
        echo "<a href='#' id='add-musica-playlist-link'>
        <img src='images/button-add-13.png' title='Adicionar à playlist' ></a>";
      }
    echo "<br><div class='separador-musica'></div></div>";    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seja o caso de imprimir, a partir do próprio PHP, o código da música no botão de adicionar. Mas antes, só uma coisa que eu reparei: é `id` ou `class`, na primeira linha do trecho abaixo?

```
echo "<a href='#' id='add-musica-playlist-link'>
      <img src='images/button-add-13.png' title='Adicionar à playlist' ></a>";
```

Acredito que você queira trocar para `class`; mas, de qualquer maneira, isto não está relacionado à sua pergunta. Vamos a ela: a modificação que você teria que fazer seria algo como:

```
echo "<a href='#' class='addMusicaPlaylistLink'>
      <input type='hidden' value='$consulta2[id_musica]' />
      <img src='images/button-add-13.png' title='Adicionar à playlist' ></a>";
```

Para ser franco, existem diversas outras maneiras de servir os dados (neste caso, o ID da música no banco de dados) para o lado cliente: atributos de dados (*data attributes*), se você estiver lidando com HTML5; injeção dos dados em outros elementos que não o `<input />`; etc.

De qualquer forma, uma vez servidos os dados via PHP, chega a parte do JavaScript de coletá-los -- ou seja, *procurá-los no DOM*. Dentro do elemento `<a>` de cada botão "Adicionar à playlist", existe um `<input />` *hidden* que contém o código da música. Por isso, na função de *callback* do seu *listener* de cada botão, deverá haver algo semelhante a isto:

(O HTML teve de ser levemente modificado em relação à marcação acima, mas o código JS serve para ambos os casos)

```js
// Aqui é apenas um exemplo de como adicionar o listener a todos os botões:
var botoes = document.getElementsByClassName("addMusicaPlaylistLink");
for(var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) botoes[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    
    // ...
  
    // Este trecho busca o código da música cujo botão foi clicado:
    var musica_id = e.srcElement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  
    // ...
  
    // Hora do AJAX! O ID da música estará na variável 'musica_id'!
    
    // ...
  
    // O trecho abaixo simplesmente mostra o código capturado, por motivos didáticos:
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "O usuário requisitou que a música " + musica_id + " fosse adicionada à playlist.";
    document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<a href='#' class='addMusicaPlaylistLink'>
    <input type='hidden' value='1234' />
    Adicionar música 1234
</a>
<br />
<a href='#' class='addMusicaPlaylistLink'>
    <input type='hidden' value='1235' />
    Adicionar música 1235
</a>
```

O trecho acima não deve ter problemas para rodar no IE9 e outros mais modernos; se você implementar outro tipo de *listener* mais compatível, provavelmente este código é capaz de rodar em browsers antiquíssimos :)

Vale notar que este JS está amarrado à minha sugestão em PHP; outros tipos de marcação exigem modificações na procura DOM realizada pelo JavaScript, então não esqueça de hackear este código até conseguir extrair seu ID para o AJAX.

Comment: obrigado! Ali é ID mesmo, ele chama uma função jQuery. Não sabia que tinha como inserir um input hidden em um <a href>. Vou testar e qualquer coisa te falo... Abs

Comment: add um alert dentro desse JS só pra ver se realmente estava chamando corretamente, e não aparece nada.. Abs

Comment: Alterei umas coisas e agora ele mostra o primeiro alert "OK", sinal que está entrando, mas o segundo não mostra, sinal que não está recuperando o valor do hidden:  document.getElementById("add-musica-playlist-link").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  alert ('OK');
  var musica_id = e.srcElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  alert(musica_id);
 });

Comment: O único problema é que esse código está dentro de um while, ou seja, pode ter mais de 1 input hidden, e nesse caso apenas o primeiro está funcionando. Será que é porque eles tem o mesmo ID? Vlw

Comment: Com certeza é por causa do ID, Ricardo :)

Troca por class, conforme eu chamei atenção no começo da minha resposta, e depois ajusta o JavaScript para buscar por classe (`getElementsByClassName("classeBotaoAdicionar")`) que vai dar certo! Só não esqueça que esse método retorna uma LISTA de elementos encontrados, será necessário iterar e adicionar o listener a cada um!

Comment: Ah, agora entendi, acho que o problema está em tratar essa LISTA, pois tanto ID ou CLASS só muda o tipo da busca, a resposta é a mesma, certo?

Comment: Peço desculpas, Ricardo, pela mancada: na verdade havia mesmo um erro, que não ficou evidente no teste que eu fiz porque só havia um único elemento com *listener*. Estava sobrando um `parentElement` dentro da função de `callback`. Aproveitei e reescrevi o trecho para funcionar com `class` ao invés de `id`. Espero que ajude! Abraços!

Comment: mudei pra CLASS, fiz exatamente como você reescreveu, ele trás o botoes.length = 3, mas simplesmente não entra no FOR.. Abraços

Comment: Talvez o `i` esteja sendo usado no meio do listener, para outra finalidade, e assim atrapalhando o loop... Ou realmente não entra? Já experimentou fazer `for(var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) console.log(botoes[i]);` pra testar?

Comment: Pior que não estou usando o i. Testei: for(var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) alert(i); e ele deu 0 1 2, certinho...

Comment: Experimenta com o console.log, que não interfere no fluxo do programa, e passando o mouse em cima dos elementos printados (pelo menos no Chrome) você consegue ver se selecionou os caras certos :D
Mas, de qualquer forma, o exemplo agora funciona e está mais próximo do seu caso... Se for necessário, abra outra pergunta com este novo problema, beleza? :)

Comment: Valeu! Vou postar uma nova pergunta... Abs e Obrigado